# Needs to ensure SMTP servers are not compromised

Tags: java, email, smtp, smtp-auth

Our Data centre is being migrated to diff. one (3rd party). The product in which we are working  have some .Net components & some Java components. All Java applications are able to send mails. But the current SMTP server is wide open, no authentication as to who is sending mail('cz it was internal to our Applications, hence no one bothered abt Authentication). Now As everything is moving out, same goes for SMTP. Now the req. is
1.We need to ensure only our Application user(i.e. user having service account with us) should be able to send mails thru SMTP. That is the sender needs to be authenticated before sending the mail. As .Net supporting windows authentication, its easy for them. But we are assuming windows auth. is not supported in Java.

How Java supports Windows auth?
If Windows authentication is not supported, what can be other approaches?